# POS tagging and NER for Chinese Text with Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

- I am trying to print the entities and pos present in Chinese text.
- I have installed # !pip3 install jieba and used Google colab for the below script.

But I am getting empty tuples for the entities and no results for pos_.

```py
from spacy.lang.zh import Chinese

nlp = Chinese()
doc = nlp(u"蘋果公司正考量用一億元買下英國的新創公司")

doc.ents
# returns (), i.e. empty tuple


for word in doc:
    print(word.text, word.pos_)

''' returns
蘋果 
公司 
正 
考量 
用 
一 
億元 
買 
下 
英國 
的 
新創 
公司 
'''
```

I am new to NLP. I want to know what is the correct way to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 3/21: Spacy now supports NER and POS tagging for CN**

Find the SpaCy model here: https://spacy.io/models/zh

**OLD ANSWER:**

SpaCy is a fantastic package, but as of yet does not support Chinese, so I assume thats the reason you dont get POS results - even though your sentence is

> "Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion"

in traditional Chinese and should therefore return "Apple" and "U.K." as `ent`, among others.

For a more extensive NLP approach to traditional Chinese, you can try using the [Stanford Chinese NLP](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/chinese-nlp.shtml) package - you are using python, and there are versions available for python (see a [demo script](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp/blob/master/demo/pipeline_demo.py) or an [intro on Medium](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/introduction-to-stanfordnlp-an-nlp-library-for-53-languages-with-python-code-d7c3efdca118)), but the original is Java, if you are more comfortable with that.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Stanford Chinese NLP.

Comment: SpaCy now has support for Chinese models: https://spacy.io/models/zh

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll make an edit to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, spaCy does not have a pretrained Chinese model yet (see [here](https://spacy.io/usage/models#languages)), which means you have to use the default `Chinese()` model which only performs tokenization, and no POS tagging or entity recognition.

There is definitely some work in progress around Chinese for spaCy though, check the issues [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/labels/lang%20%2F%20zh).